# How to get the "Reason" details in "loyalty points redeem_history"

Tags: magento2, invoice, reward-points

In Magento 2.4., I need to get the "Reason" details in "reward points redeem_history". It is not coming with default "redeem_history" collection. Only comments are coming. How we can get it?